# Lua inner conflicts with C/Delphi functions?

Tags: api, lua

I made timer implementation for my project (for lua 5.1, full sources, dll and test available at http://wintarif.narod.ru/products.htm so I will skip full sources in question). Timer creates objects and implements CreateTimerQueueTimer. I made 3 tests with different behavior:
shared part of test script

```
require('timer')

-- params same as CreateTimerQueueTimer: DueTime, Period, Flags
-- flag WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE = 8, timer will stops, enabled set to false
local mt = timer(1000, 1000, 0)

local i = 0;
function myOnTimer()
    print('wow!')
    if i < 5 then
        i = i + 1
    else
        print("stopping timer")
        mt:StopTimer()
    end
end

mt:SetEvent('OnTimer', myOnTimer)
mt:StartTimer()
```

when I using

```
while mt:GetEnabled() do --more buggy way
end
```

there is "unhandled exception", but it prints `wow!` every second nonstop.
With

```
while true do --buggy way, stack conflict during callback?
    local enabled = mt:GetEnabled()
    if not(enabled) then
        break
    end
end
```

errors like `5: bad argument #-2 to 'GetEnabled' (attempt to concatenatetimerLOADLIB:  a table valuetimerstring)` or `5: bad argument #-2 to 'GetEnabled' (timer expected, got table)` or it can work until first event from dll and stops without errors.

Only

```
function WaitForTimer()
    while true do
        local is_enabled = mt:GetEnabled()
        if not(is_enabled) then
            print("not enabled")
            return coroutine.yield()
        end
    end
end

co = coroutine.create(WaitForTimer)
coroutine.resume(co)
```

works without errors.

Dll implementation for `GetEnabled()` quite simple, static cdecl function

```
function StaticThunk(L: Plua_State): integer; cdecl;
var
  o: TLuaWrapper;
begin
  o := TLuaWrapper(lua_topointer(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
  result := o.Thunk(L);
end;
```

that extracts object, object's Thunk

```
function TLuaWrapper.Thunk(L: Plua_State): integer;
var
  i: integer;
  pobj: PtrT;
begin
  { redirect method call to the real thing }
  i := lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(2)); // function's index, index is 2 since 1 is self ptr now
  lua_pushnumber(L, 0);
  lua_gettable(L, 1); // get the class table (i.e, self)

  pobj := PtrT(luaL_checkudata(L, -1, PAnsiChar(REG_NAME)));
  lua_remove(L, -1); // remove the userdata from the stack
  lua_remove(L, 1); // remove object from the stack

  try
    result := ClassApiArray[i].func(L, pobj^); // execute the thunk
  except
      result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

and exact

```
function TLuaWrapper.GetEnabled(L: Plua_State; obj: TQueuedTimer): integer;
begin
  // lua_settop(L, 0);
  lua_pushboolean(L, obj.Enabled);
  result := 1;
end;
```

What exactly happens inside Lua? Why I have conflicts?

More info: script executed under `lua.exe` from `LuaForWindows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function passed to `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` will be executed by Windows asynchronously **in another thread**.
But you are not allowed to work with the same Lua state from two different threads simultaneously.
Thus, you can't execute callback function in Lua state while your main script is running in this Lua state.
Using Lua state from multiple threads would lead to unpredictable behavior and weird error messages.
Your code with coroutines, which currently works without errors, would also get errors once your callback function become more complex.

Lua state is not thread-safe.
So, functionality of `CreateTimerQueueTimer` is not bindable to Lua.  Пичалька  :-(

Comment: Errors in 2 buggy scripts occurs even before first callback occurs (DueTime 1000ms) and (my research) when I using not Lua.exe from `LuaForWindows` but Lua environment (application that uses Lua51.dll) made under Delphi (FastMM4 memory manager) there is no errors at all. Question was about what Lua does: allocating memory for stack, puts data in stack, calls function, function extracts data from stack and tables and returns data through same stack, Lua garbage collecting local variables? Right? Why there errors?

Comment: @user2091150 - Your test case is very large.  Please write a tiny program (Delphi+Lua) which exhibits your error and doesn't use callback function.

Comment: The problem is: I have no problems with `Hello Worlds` :)

Comment: @user2091150 - Probably, Blizzard forces to run all callback functions in main thread (like `synchronize` in Delphi forces to execute your procedure in VCL thread).  Do you have a link to description of working with events in Blizzard's Lua environment?

Comment: Blizzard's documentations is known by absence. However there is a lot of documentation made by another developers (WoWWiki, Wowpedia etc). I made many complicated addons and liked idea of using complicated templates in xml (like panel with many elements to reuse) and decided to make the same with Delphi (wish I know what for). Addons driven by events from WoW client, as addon devs we just using them. By rumors Blizzard using queue so I tried right now to enqueue timer's event and call callback on `QueueChanged` from wrapper's class (with moderate success).

Comment: So first part of my project is done: I can make complicated templates in xml with Vcl components, put them on form from script, but I really want to use normal things like event driven iocp based serial ports, timers, `OnClick`, `OnChange` etc.

Comment: @user2091150 - You can't make fair callback functions in Lua, but it's possible to implement `wait_any_event(array_of_events)` function in Delphi and make it available to your Lua code.